# The target table Result of the DELETE is not updatable. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, subquery, common-table-expression

I have tried using CTE and subquery both of them giving same error as "The target table Result of the DELETE is not updatable". I tried google but I did not found useful resources.

[customers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6yLU.jpg)

CTE code

```
with Result as
(
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as RowNo 
    from 
        customers
)
delete from Result 
where RowNo > 1;
```

Subquery code

```
delete Result 
from (select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as RowNo 
      from customers) Result 
where Result.RowNo > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.ident_column = t2.ident_column
             AND t1.order_column < t2.order_column
```

or

```
DELETE
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t1.ident_column = t2.ident_column
                 AND t1.order_column < t2.order_column )
```

This pattern deletes rows which are duplicates by `ident_column` saving only the row with greatest value in `order_column` for a group.

Comment: i am trying like this `DELETE t1 FROM customers t1 JOIN customers t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.id < t2.id;` query is executing with 0 row(s) affected

Comment: @RamE Please think firstly. `t1.id` cannot be both equal and less than `t2.id` at the same time.

Comment: i have updated my table in the question can you please once see it?

Comment: @RamE Sample data must be provided as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and accompanied by desired final data state.

Comment: @RamE In your screenshot the duplicated rows are complete duplicates. If this is complete state of your table then you cannot perform needed action in the single query form.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM customers 
WHERE id IN( 
           WITH cte AS (
               SELECT id, row_number() over(partition by id order by id) AS RowNo FROM customers) 
           SELECT id FROM cte WHERE RowNo>1
);
```

This should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).